# How do I prevent my script from crashing if condition is not met?

Tags: python, loops, file, match

I am trying to build a script that fetches certain pieces of information from a bunch of .txts and append them to a csv. The .txt files are processing logs from a software. Each project I run generates a log, and I need to fetch infos to build up monthly reports.

What I have: A script that runs through every one of these logs in a folder, finds pieces of strings (the info I need), and puts them in a new csv. It works if all the conditions in the .txts are met.

Problem I have: If one of the .txts doesn't meet the script requirements (ie: doesn't have the piece of string I am looking for), the script stops running and returns an error.

There are certainly more efficient ways to do this, but this is what I have so far:

```
import re
import os.path, sys
import csv

path = r"C:\Users\r o d r i g o\Desktop\001 - progamer\python\03 - logpix\relatorios" 
dirs = os.listdir(path)

relatorio =  open(r'C:\Users\r o d r i g o\Desktop\001 - progamer\python\03 - logpix\relatorios\relatorio.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(relatorio)
writer.writerow(['log', 'Nome', 'Projeção', 'Câmera', 'Número de fotos', 'Image Scale', 'Point Density', 'Min Number Matches', 'Step 1', 'Step 2'])
```

Above, I define path (where my .txts are) and write the first line of my csv

```
def script():
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)
        if fullpath.endswith(".txt"):
            logpix = open(fullpath)
            head, tail = os.path.split(fullpath)
            x = logpix.read()

            m_name = re.search('Name                    = <(.*)>', x)
            m_proj = re.search('WKT Output              = <PROJCS(.*),GEOGCS', x)
            m_cammodel = re.search('camera model <(.*)(RGB)', x)
            m_numimg = re.search('Cameras with (.*) different images', x)
            m_imscale = re.search('Image scale               = <(.*)>', x)
            m_ptdens = re.search('Point density             = <(.*)>', x)
            m_match = re.search('Minimum number of matches = <(.*)>', x)
            m_step1 = re.search('Step1<<< done in (.*)ms', x)
            m_step2 = re.search('Step2<<< done in (.*)ms', x)

            name = m_name.group(1)
            proj = m_proj.group(1)
            cammodel = m_cammodel.group(1)
            numimg = m_numimg.group(1)
            imscale = m_imscale.group(1)
            ptdens = m_ptdens.group(1)
            match = m_match.group(1)
            step1 = m_step1.group(1)
            step2 = m_step2.group(1)


            writer.writerow([tail, name, proj, cammodel, numimg, imscale, ptdens, match, step1, step2])

script()

relatorio.close()
```

Above, I use os to circle through each .txt file; then use re.search to find the information I need; create variables to turn those into strings;  write these variables into a csv.

Problem is, some of the .txts might not have one of the variables I'm creating (won't have Step 2 for example, or won't have Camera model). If that is the case, my csv comes out blank, and I get an error message:

```
 in script()
     29             name = m_name.group(1)
     30             proj = m_proj.group(1)
---> 31             cammodel = m_cammodel.group(1)
     32             numimg = m_numimg.group(1)
     33             imscale = m_imscale.group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

In this example, one of the files didn't have a camera model.

How do I tell my program to ignore a variable if it can't find it? Or fill it with N/A?

I tried to play with some if-else but I can't grasp where to put it. Any help is much appreciated, even if just to nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to check the results of all the `re.search()` calls, to make sure they succeeded.

Comment: `if m_name and m_proj and ...:`

Comment: Might be overkill, but in general the Python structure to use would be a `try/except[/else/finally]` block. I think the method in the comment by @Barmar is the correct way to go for your issue of potentially missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `re.search` returns `None` when no match was found, you can simply do:

```
cammodel = m_cammodel and m_cammodel.group(1)
```

so that `cammodel` would be assigned `None` when `m_cammodel` is `None`.

Comment: Ha, this is why I'm loving coding more each day. Simple yet well, it works. I will use it for now, but I'll definetly try the other awnsers in case I run into a similar problem again (I'll have to learn it at some point after all). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following to be pseudocode. You can also use a `try-catch` rather than an if-statement since exceptions are cheap in Python:

```
def main():

    # ...

    from pathlib import Path

    for path in Path("path/to/textfiles").rglob("*.txt"):
        patterns = {
            "name": "Name: <(.*)>",
            "age": "Age: (.*)",
            "foo": "FooMeter: (\d+)"
        }

        with path.open("r") as file:
            content = file.read()
            row = []
            for key, pattern in patterns.items():
                match = re.search(pattern, content)
                if match is None:
                    row.append("")
                else:
                    row.append(match.group(1))

            writer.writerow(row)
```